# Finding deg(f) with invariant

Tags: functions

> Let $S = \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$. Consider a function $f\colon S\to S$. A subset $D$ of $S$ is said to be invariant if for all $x\in D$ we have $f(x)\in D$. The empty set and $S$ are also considered as invariant subsets. By $\deg (f)$ we define the number of invariant subsets $D$ of $S$ for the function $f$.
>
> [b]i)[/b] Show that there exists a function $f\colon S\to S$ such that $\deg (f)=2$.
>
> [b]ii)[/b] Show that for every $1\leq k\leq n$ there exists a function $f\colon S\to S$ such that $\deg (f)=2^{k}$.
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$ {S} =$ {$1,2,...,n$}
 .  $f:S \to f$
 .  $D\subset S$
1.consider a function f(x)=x+1 $\forall x \in S$ consider 
   $n+1 \to 1$
Means a cyclical function.
So ,we can consideronly two sunsets A,B so that if $x\in A$ then $f(x)\in A$.
As it is easy to note that $S$ and $\Phi$ are both invariant under $f$.

2.now consider a subset $B={1,2,......,r} where r\le n$ 
We always get a function $f:S\to B $ now a subset of $S$ will invariant under $f$ if it consists $B$ also .so number of such subset is $2^{n-|B|}$.
So $deg (f)=2^{n-r}$.
 By similar arguement let $D\subset S$ so that $D$={$k+1,....,n$}.
and consider a function $g:s\to D$
$deg(g) = 2^k 1\ge k \le n$. $\square$                            QED

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find the $\deg$ of the two functions
$$f(x) = x$$ $$g(x) = \begin{cases}x+1 & \text{ if } x \neq n \\ 1 & \text{ if }x=n\end{cases}$$
One will give you the answer to part **i)**, and if you combine what you've learned from both of them, you'll find the answer to part **ii)**

Comment: Elaborate pls .....

Comment: @TrishanMondal What do you need clarified?  Have you computed $\deg(f)$ and $\deg(g)$ yet?

Comment: So degree of $f$ is $2^n$... now how to construct a set of degree $2^k$...hmm is it like $g$ such that there are $k-1$ constant points ? @BrianMoehring